# JSP Beans and AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, javabeans

I'm new in using beans and still gettng used to it.
I got this code:

```
<form class="Bar" action="Add" method="post" ng-repeat="item in bars">
<p> 
    <jsp:useBean id="barID" class="com.JavaBeans.BarBean" scope="application" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="barID" property="name" value= "{{item.name}}"/>
```

and I want to display the content of `{{item.name}}` in another JSP.
AngularJS is integrated in that JSP.
If I set

```
<jsp:getProperty name="barID" property="name"/>
```

in the current JSP, everything's fine but as soon as I try to do this in the other JSP I just get {{item.name}} as a String Output, the property is a String

Probably an obvious mistake. Before I start doing something very complicated, I was wondering if there is an simple solution

Comment: I think you have somewhat of a critical misunderstanding in how client-side and server-side code can interact.

Comment: hmmm yeah, thought that ^^,  can you give me a hint where this misunderstanding is?

Comment: The JSP code is run on the server; there's no way whatsoever the `ng-repeat="item in bars"` can pass anything to it. Therefore, there's no (sic!) `item` the JSP variable in scope, therefore `{{item.name}}` cannot be rendered... not to say that JSP EL has a `${item.name}` syntax.

Comment: The way i see it, all of your `<jsp: . . .>` tags are going to run once on the server. The output HTML/JS is rendered and sent to the client. The client then runs the javascript (angularjs). At that point, it's far too late for angularjs to inject a value back into the JSP tag as from the perspective of the client (and thus angular), it's just plain old HTML.

Comment: ah i see, thanks! is there a way how i can display the content on another html/jsp dynamically?